# Check if a value is less than another one

Tags: jquery, html

I know this might seem stupid but I'm having trouble checking 2 values against each other. The following codes I used them several times and they work, but on one instance it simply does weird things.
On the front page I got:

```
<input type=\"text\" name=\"v571\" id=\"v571\" value=\"\" size=\"18\"/>
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"v571a\" id=\"v571a\" value=\"140\"/>
```

In the js script I have:

```
if( $('#v571').val() > $('#v571a').val()) {
    $('#v571').addClass('error');
    error++;
}
```

These are the results:

```
if v571 betweem 100 and 140 -> no error (should get no error)
if v571 less then 100 -> error (should get an error)
if v571 bigger then 140 -> error (should get an error)
if v571 bigger then 140 , but the number starts with 1 (eg: 1000, 1200, 12312, 1xxx...) -> no error (should get an error)
if v571 is 1,10,11 it's ok (should get no error)
if v571 is anything else less then 100 -> error (should get no error)
```

I also got this that works perfect:

```
<input type=\"text\" name=\"v572\" id=\"v572\" value=\"\" size=\"18\"/>
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"v572a\" id=\"v572a\" value=\"148\"/>
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"v572b\" id=\"v572b\" value=\"152\"/>
```

and the js:

```
if( $('#v572').val() < $('#v572a').val() || $('#v572').val() > $('#v572b').val()) {
    $('#v572').addClass('error');
    error++;
}
```

Comment: Make sure to compare numbers with numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to compare integers:

```
var v1 = parseInt($('#v571').val(),10); // always use a radix
var v2 = parseInt($('#v571a').val(),10);
if( v1 > v2) {
    $('#v571').addClass('error');
    error++;
}
```

Comment: that is the only place that acts weird. I have on multiple instances different values that get compared (11.0<x<13.3) (-13<x<-11.0) (4.8<x<5.2) and so one. All work flawless. This simple one no

Comment: Use parsefloat if you are comparing floats: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp

Comment: I have tried if( $('#v571').val() > 140) {...} but the same thing

Comment: When you compare two strings, it compares them lexicographically. That means that '100' < '9' since it compares '1' and '9' first and '9' is bigger lexicographically.
parseint basically converts a string into a number and compares it the way you want. Since we are talking about integers this is relevant only for whole numbers.
If you want to compare float numbers(e.g 13.12) then use parsefloat for that. You need to convert the string into the relevant type and only then compare it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( parseInt($('#v571').val()) > parseInt($('#v571a').val())) {
    $('#v571').addClass('error');
    error++;
}
```

Comment: same errors. v571a will either be 140 or 150, it depends on some things. If less then 100 I still get errors unless 1,10,11. If bigger then 145//150 if it starts with "1" (1xxx) I get no error